# Problem launching Google Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, launch

i tried since many hours to launch navigation from my app.
I want navigation without destination.

i tried with

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="));
        startActivity(i);
```

That launches navigation but with destination not found

I tried too to launch processName, packageName with startIntent with **com.google.android.apps.maps**,
**com.google.android.apps.maps:driveabout and 
**com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.DestinationActivity**

with no succes too :/

an idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Navigation does not have any documented and supported `Intent` filters. It is not designed to be integrated from third party apps.

Answer (score 4):

The following code should work...

```
String url = "google.navigation:q="+startPos.getLatitude()+","+startPos.getLongitude();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));            
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This is not documented and is not supported on some devices, I highly encourage you not to use it

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look a the intent filter for Google Navigation. It could be that it is not designed to be started via Intent without a specified destination. Unfortunately, i don't know where to find information about Google Navigation's intent filter, but if you were to show me where you are looking i could help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
google.navigation:fd=true
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't want to integrate it, i just want to launch it like a click on the list of apps whith a home launcher.

I've tried the google home sample, and navigation can be launched.
but i don't understand why that doesn't work with my own app :/